# Fibonacci Search Method in R

Tags: python, r, fibonacci

I am trying to rewrite [Fibonacci Search method](https://indrag49.github.io/Numerical-Optimization/solving-one-dimensional-optimization-problems.html#fibonacci-search-method) from python to R.

The R code so far.

```
fibonacci <- function(n) {
  fn <- c(1,1)
  for (i in 2:n+1) {
    fn <- c(fn, (fn[i-1]+fn[i-2]))
  }
  return(fn)
}
```

and

```
fib_search <- function(f, xl, xr, n){
  F = fibonacci(n) # Call the fibonnaci number function
  L0 = xr - xl # Initial interval of uncertainty
  R1 = L0 # Initial Reduction Ratio
  Li = (F[n-2]/F[n])*L0 
  
  R = Li/L0
  
  for (i in 2:n+1)
  {
    if (Li > L0/2) {
      x1 = xr - Li
      x2 = xl + Li
    } else {
      x1 = xl + Li
      x2 = xr - Li
    }
    f1 = f(x1)
    f2 = f(x2)
    
    if (f1 < f2) {
      xr = x2
      Li = (F[n - i]/F[n - (i - 2)])*L0 # New interval of uncertainty
    } else if (f1 > f2) {
      xl = x1
      Li = (F[n - i]/F[n - (i - 2)])*L0 # New interval of uncertainty
    } else {
      xl = x1
      xr = x2
      Li = (F[n - i]/F[n - (i - 2)])*(xr - xl) # New interval of uncertainty
    }
    L0 = xr - xl
    R = c(R, Li/R1)
  }
  
  list1 <- list(x1, f(x1), R)
  list2 <- list(x2, f(x2), R)
  if (f1 <= f2) {
    return(list1) # Final result
  } else {
    return(list2) # Final result 
  }
}
```

When I try to use the **fib_search** function with

```
f <- function(x) {
  x**5 - 5*x**3 - 20*x + 5
}

Fib = fib_search(f, -2.5, 2.5, 25)
```

I always get an error message.

> Error in if (Li > L0/2) { : argument is of length zero

When I try to run it line by line, I got it running (but of course, it just for a specific value, not for the iteration).

Comment: It seems most likely that the culprit is `Li`, as defined with `(F[n-2]/F[n])*L0 `. If `n` is out of the range of `F` (you never check) then it will not work as intended. (Notably, `if (1[0] > 1/2) 1 else 2` reproduces that error in the same basic context, suggesting that your `Li` is neither length > 1 nor `NA` (which would in a different error, see `if (1[2] > 1/2) 1 else 2`). Perhaps you should add something like `if (length(F) < n) browser()` so that you can troubleshoot what else is going on.

Comment: The error occurs on the 25th (or 24th or so, I lost count) iteration of your loop, where both `n` and `i` are `25`; from there, `F[n - i]` is `F[0]` which returns `numeric(0)` which is going to fail. If you change your `i` loop to `for (i in 2:n)`, it works, though I don't know if that _logic_ is correct for your application. (For the record, `2:n+1` is different from `2:(n+1)`, though they both fail the same way.)

Comment: Ahhh, silly me.. I think your suggestion for i loops is correct. I forgot to consider that python index start from 0, different from R that start from 1.